# Gulp watch/src only one level down

Tags: javascript, gulp, src, watch

In gulp watch and src I can do this for matching all js files in any folder within that parent.

```
modules/**/*.js
```

The problem I have is that I don't want it to match grandchildren of that module. It should not match this:

```
modules/header/component/subfolder/plugin.js
modules/hero/field/script.js
```

But I want it should match these:

```
modules/header/test.js
modules/hero/script.js
```

Only one level down. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` matches all on one level so you can do: `modules/*/*.js`